# How to change color of lines using R and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently using this code

```
q <- ggplot(data = graph_data, aes(x = Year_NA)) +    
  geom_line(aes(y = MTCT_rate_at_before_birth_mean,color = "blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(
    y = Postnatal_MTCT_rate_to_18_months_from_HIV_diagnosed_mothers_mean,
    color = "orange"
  )) +
   labs(title= "MTCT rate postnatal vs. prenatal Vs. Year",  
       y="MTCT Rate", x= "Year") + 
    scale_colour_discrete(name = "", labels = c("MTC before birth", "MTCT after birth")) +
 theme_bw() 
 show(q)
```

however the colors of the lines are not changing to orange or blue and I am trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: You put mappings **to columns in your data** inside `aes()`. If you just want to set a constant, you do that outside `aes()`. Change `geom_line(aes(y = MTCT_rate_at_before_birth_mean,color = "blue"))` to `geom_line(aes(y = MTCT_rate_at_before_birth_mean) ,color = "blue")` (and similarly for the other line).

Comment: Though if you want the scale and default legend to work nicely, then you should [pivot your data to a long/tidy format  (link to FAQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/903061) where you have single column with all the `y` values and another column, say "MTC Timing" indicating whether it is "MTC before birth" "MTCT after birth", and then you would do a single `geom_line(aes(y = y_column, color = MTC_Timing))`.

Comment: is there a way to keep the legend or create a new one using the first method?

Comment: Yes, but I never do it because I can never remember how.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(graph_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(graph_data, 20))`.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037615/add-customized-legends-to-geom-line-in-r) on customized legends and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75499124/how-do-i-make-my-plot-from-r-look-like-the-one-i-have-on-python) on colors. This question is basically a duplicate.

Comment: It is, imo, messier than pivoting to a long format as @GregorThomas suggested, but can be done. In the `geom_line` aesthetics you create a variable to map to, then call `scale_color_manual`. ```geom_line(aes(y = MTCT_rate_at_before_birth_mean,color = "before"))+
  geom_line(aes(
    y = Postnatal_MTCT_rate_to_18_months_from_HIV_diagnosed_mothers_mean,
    color = "18months")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("before" = "blue", "18months" = "orange"))```